# LogicApp error: azure cannot reach host runtime. Error details, Code: 'Unauthorized', Message: 'Encountered an error (Forbidden) from extensions API.'

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

When I try to access the **workflows** of an Azure Logic App (Standard), I am getting the error:

**azure cannot reach host runtime. Error details, Code: 'Unauthorized', Message: 'Encountered an error (Forbidden) from extensions API.'**

[image: logic app error]

Same for other sections, like **Connections**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is quite cryptic, this was simply caused by the Azure Logic App being stopped. Once it was started, the workflows and other sections were available.